# How do you record a Skype conversation on Windows?

Tags: windows-vista, skype, audio-recording

Is there an app or plugin for Skype to record a conversation?

Or can you use an audio application like Sonar or Sony Vegas Studio to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Pamela for Skype](http://www.pamela.biz/en/)** is the ultimate tool for managing all your Skype calls.

Features

```
* Skype Call Recording
* Skype Video Recording
* Skype Chat Recording
* Skype Call Transfer
* Rich Mood Editor
* Answering Machine
* VideoMail
* Mega Emotion Sounds
* Auto Chat Reply
* Birthday Reminders
* Email Forwarding
* Contact Personalization
* Auto Start Applications
* Skype Publishing
```

Comment: Automatic call recording not available on the free version.

Comment: free version has maximum 15 minute recording limit

Answer (score 5):

I use [MP3 Skype Recorder](http://voipcallrecording.com/).

The MP3 files can be edited using Audacity.

Comment: no restrictions on maximum recording time

Comment: not dependent on your soundcard-hardware/drivers like the audacity answer

Comment: can it save the voices of the parties in separate channels?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/), and select the "Wave Out Mix" for the audio input.  This should record your Skype call.

Comment: In a nutshell: This solution only works if you have specific hardware/driver features in your soundcard. Long story: You need a soundcard that allows you to route the microphone and speakers through one recording device. [Not all soundcards are able to do this](http://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=63467). Even if you can route the microphone and speakers correctly the soundcard drivers may then prevent you from opening the input to record from. So ya... hardware/driver dependent solution.

Comment: yes but the problem is that you will not record your own voice unless you playback your microphone through your speakers.

Answer (score 2):

[Call Graph](http://lifehacker.com/374720/record-skype-calls-as-mp3s-with-call-graph) ([here](http://scribie.com/blog/)) is one of these apps.

Some other inexpensive apps - [Hotrecorder](http://www.hotrecorder.com/), [Pamela](https://www.pamela.biz/shop/pamela_call_recorder_1?category_id=0), [Freecorder](http://vixy.net/download.php)

[Call Graph](http://scribie.com/blog/), which is also **free**,  works fine, and it even saves a dual-channel recording if you set recording as stereo (wave or mp3).

[image: Call Graph Configuration]

Then, you can split and then edit, save or just hear separately each of the channel (ideal for an interview and other purposes where the two voices may overlap and need to be separated) if you open it in Audacity and then split the stereo track.

[image: Audacity]

Answer (score 1):

Another program worth mentioning that does Skype recording is [vEmotion](http://www.voiceemotion.com). The program also works for other VoIP clients and provides music sharing, text-to-speech, voice emotion functions beside recording.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I work for the company.

[My Screen Recorder](http://www.deskshare.com/msr.aspx) is one of the many programs that can record audio.  You can also use it to record video should you do a video call or share desktops.

Comment: Also $ 39.95 . .

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PrettyMay Call Recorder for Skype](http://www.prettymay.net/callrecorder/)

Answer (score 0):

From [How to Record Skype Conversations](http://labnol.blogspot.com/2006/06/how-to-record-skype-conversations.html), here are the free products:

[**PowerGramo Recorder for Skype**](http://www.powergramo.com/)

> PowerGramo Free version is a good
>   option if the Skype conversation
>   involves only two persons. The Skype
>   call can be of any duration and will
>   be recorded in the OGG or WAV format.
>   The pro version supports Multiple-call
>   people conference recording.
>   PowerGramo will work on older versions
>   of Skype include Skype 1.1
>   [Free/$19.95]

[**PrettyMay**](http://www.prettymay.net/)

> PrettyMay is another voice recording
>   add-on popular among Skype users.
>   PrettyMay is absolutely free though
>   the maximum recording time is limited
>   to 30 minutes. PrettyMay can record
>   both Skype incoming calls and outgoing
>   calls in either .wav or .mp3 audio
>   formats. [Free]

[**Build your own Skype Recorder**](http://www.henshall.com/docs/Skype%20Recording%20WinXp%2012202004.pdf)

> This PDF document titled has
>   instructions to building your own
>   Skype recording studio using Windows
>   Sound Recorder and Virtual Audio
>   Cable, a Windows WDM multimedia
>   driver. The author uses this to record
>   Podcasts using Skype. You can also use
>   this approach with Audacity or Adobe
>   Audition for recording and editing the
>   quality of voice. VAC needs no audio
>   card; it is a "virtual audio card"
>   itself. You need two instances of
>   Skype running on the same computer.

Answer (score 0):

One more Skype recorder which automatically stores you Skype history in email folders - http://skype2email.com

*Skype2email is a commercial program with a 14 days free trial.

Disclaimer: I worked on this program.*

Answer (score 0):

There's also [G-Recorder](http://www.g-recorder.com) plugin for Skype:

- records Skype calls automatically saves them to your mailbox and/or
  to disk
- saves chat history along with call recordings in view of
  conversations
- has free edition

*Disclaimer: I'm a co-author of G-Recorder*

Answer (score 0):

There is another program that performs this task for free, Free Video Call Recorder for Skype http://dvdvideosoft.com/products/dvd/Free-Video-Call-Recorder-for-Skype.htm

Answer (score -1):

Lots of free skype recorders are available,such as ifree call recorder.
Also some video skype recorder if you want, [Evaer skype video recorder](http://www.evaer.com), IMcapture etc.