# What the best audio recording software for phone calls?

Tags: skype, recording

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [record phone conversation on a WM device](https://superuser.com/questions/68915/record-phone-conversation-on-a-wm-device)
>   [How do you record a Skype conversation on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/54035/how-do-you-record-a-skype-conversation-on-windows)

I want to record phone conferences and would like to know what the best software combination out there is to do this.

I know a lot of people recommend using Skype to record phone calls, what else is needed?

Comment: Please see http://superuser.com/questions/54035/how-do-you-record-a-skype-conversation-on-windows for the answer to "what else is needed?"

Comment: I think it may be illegal to record calls unless the call being recorded is disclosed. I think...

Comment: Or: http://superuser.com/questions/68915/record-phone-conversation-on-a-wm-device

Comment: first duplicate link (question 54035) is a better match; the second is asking about software for Windows Mobile devices.

Comment: In future, please review all the duplicates listed during the Ask the Question stage before asking a question. Duplicate questions will be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to record phone conferences

**[Pamela for Skype](http://www.pamela.biz/en/)** will do that for you (the free version allows recordings of up to 15 minutes)

Comment: In future please confirm a question is not a duplicate before answering. Duplicate questions should be closed. Providing answers to these questions encourages new users to do the same instead of flagging questions to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try [vEmotion](http://www.voiceemotion.com/).

From the website:

- All pc based (pc to pc, pc to phone,
  phone to pc) VoIP calls can be
  recorded.
- Record calls into mp3 with
  rate up to 48000 Hz. That's better
  than CD quality!
- Automatically start
  and complete call recording.
- Automatically select record file name
  according to preset format strings.
- Epoch recorded. Remember the exact
  time you said some words!
- Write memo while recording a call, and save memo
  together with call records.
- Save multiple records for a single call,
  manually or automatically.
- Have data and information encrypted and
  password protected for safety.
- Manage (sort, find, star, replay, share)
  call records very easily.
- Easily share call records: send records via
  email or play records as shared
  music.
- Ability to run as background
  service (stealth mode) showing no
  user interface.
- Plus an embedded
  general pc recorder it's a perfect
  tool for daily recording, podcasting,
  online journalism, and much more!

Comment: In future please confirm a question is not a duplicate before answering. If it is please flag for moderator attention and add your answer to the duplicate question.