# Difference between "Realtek Digital Input" and "Stereo Mix"

Tags: audio, drivers, windows-vista, audio-recording

When trying to record sound through CamStudio on Windows Vista, I found that I had to change the recording device to from "Realtek Digital Input" to "Stereo Mix".
(Control Panel>sound>Recording>Show Disabled Devices>Enable Stereo Mix)

Are there any drawbacks to this? What is the difference between the "Realtek Digital Input" and "Stereo Mix", and what are some of the pro/cons of each?

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/753064/167187

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Stereo Mix supposed to be used for in Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/753061/what-is-stereo-mix-supposed-to-be-used-for-in-windows)

Comment: I believe Realtek Digital Output is used to [output audio from your PC via HDMI or optical connections](http://everydaylife.globalpost.com/enable-realtek-digital-output-31902.html). Check my earlier comment to learn what Stereo Mix is.

Comment: @Vinayak I'm asking as to the difference between the two and the pros/cons of each.

Comment: The basic difference is that one of them is a playback device while the other is a recording device. Pros and cons of each? I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: @Vinayak They are both listed under "Recording Devices". By pros/cons I mean what would happen differently if I choose each one.

Comment: @Vinayak Oops, I had meant "Realtek Digital *Input*". Just realized my mistake.

Comment: As @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 mentions in the linked answer, Stereo Mix is a virtual audio device which downmixes all audio output and presents it as stereo input (2 channels) so you can record the sound coming out from your speakers. If you have a Line In socket on your computer, Realtek Digital Input probably lets you record audio from that.

Comment: Nice question. I had to do the same thing. I tried for hours and had volume issues and then changed the settings like you did and it worked. Frustrating as hell. That was a couple years ago, but I remember how frustrating that was. Definitely an over site on the programmer. And CamStudion crashes all the time and takes a lot of resources.

Comment: @ejbytes I'm now trying to figure out whether to keep the settings this way constantly or to switch it every time I use camstudio.

Comment: @ibid I'ts been a while, but I think you can put your settings back. If I recall I had to enable something in the sound (control panel) but didn't have to set it. I think it's in the CamStudio Options. On the "record inputs" panel, click the microphone drop-down and choose "Record System Audio". Look around in the application options and preferences.   It was a while ago, but I'm checking out my settings right now.