# Can I retrieve a microphone recording when I set the input device to stereo mix?

Tags: audio

I have just made an interview through a phone call (on speaker).
My computer was set to record the call through a microphone.
But after the entire interview I found out that the input device was set on "stereo mix", and I cannot hear any sound on my recording.

Is there a way to get sound on the recording I have and get a recording of my phone call?

Answer (score 0):

If during the recording the input source was set to **stereo mix** the computer recorded sounds that happened on the computer itself (e.g. a video playing). It's as if you recorded the headphone port of your computer.

It did not record any sound coming from the microphone that was set-up to record your phone call, only in [the off chance that you we're **listening** to your microphone](https://superuser.com/a/753064/141595) through your computer during the recording.

Unfortunately this makes it very likely that you have no recording of your phone call.